# Getting more out of Minkowski's convex body theorem in the case of non-convex bodies

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, lattices

**Problem.** In number theory one generally proves the finiteness of the Picard group of a number field using Minkowski's convex body theorem. The actual body $S_p$ of interest in the proof, depending on some parameter $p$, is symmetric but not convex. We proceed by isolating the largest symmetric convex subset $C$ of $S_p$. The result is a worse bound on the $p$ for which we can find non-zero lattice points in $S_p$, than if we were allowed to apply Minkowski to $S_p$ instead of $C$.

**Question.** Are there general techniques to get better results than such a 'wasteful' application of Minkowski's theorem for symmetric but non-convex bodies? With general I mean applicable to some lattices and bodies, but not necessarily to the above problem.

The case I am particularly interested in is asymptotic: I have for every dimension $d$ a lattice $\Lambda_d$ and a symmetric body $S_d$ such that $\log(\text{vol}(S_d)/\text{det}(\Lambda_d))=\Theta(d^2)$ and want to find a $d$ and a non-zero lattice point in $\Lambda_d\cap S_d$.

Comment: Dear MadPidgeon, Could you please remind us what are the geometrical properties of this symmetrical but non convex body ? Or maybe give us a reference where we could find them ? Many thanks in advance.